# real-valued functions on the modular surface

Tags: cv.complex-variables

How does one write down $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on the modular surface?  I am considering taking an arbitrary function on the upper half plane $f:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{R}$ and averaging over the elements of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.  So, 
$$ f_1(z) = \sum_{g \in SL(2, \mathrm{Z})} f(gz) $$
there may have to be a decay condition on $f$ so the function will converge.  I am not necessarily looking for holomorphic functions, just smooth and well defined on $\mathbb{H}\backslash SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I must be missing something: what counts as "writing down a function"? There are going to be a plethora of non-zero smooth functions on this surface, so what other properties or identities are you looking for?

Comment: Take any smooth function of the j-invariant?

Comment: In the absence of an application or additional context, it is hard to tell if you would prefer a universal answer as given by Yemon and Qiaochu, or something more structured.

Comment: It could be the word I am looking for is "modular function".  Does the j-invvariant have a Fourier series?  What are the critical values?

Answer (score 3):

You may have an easier time starting with a function that is periodic under translation by 1, then summing over cosets of translation in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.  If your initial function is well-behaved, your sum will converge (although often one introduces correction terms to get sections of a line bundle, i.e., modular forms of nonzero weight). This is a common method for constructing Poincaré series, [Real-analytic Eisenstein series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analytic_Eisenstein_series) (where $f$ is given by a power of the imaginary part), and [Rademacher sums](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4529) (where $f$ is exponential).

Comment: 
To supplement Scott, see Gunning's Lectures on Modular Forms, Chapter 3. This "sum over cosets" technique is discussed there.  http://books.google.com/books?id=UBwjJAiMZtcC&lpg=PP1&dq=gunning%20lectures%20modular%20forms&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false